# How do I do multiple things (e.g., change values in multiple columns) in a dataframe for rows that meet specific if conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm a SAS programmer trying to translate my code to python.  The SAS code shown below checks for multiple if conditions, and if true then the do statement allows me to change the values in multiple columns:

```
if state_text eq 'ALASKA' and country_code ne 'US' then do;
    flag=1;
    country_code='US';
    state_code='AK';
end;
```

What is the equivalent for a pandas dataframe? I'm having trouble getting the recodes to apply only to the rows that meet the if condition. The code below does the job but seems very duplicative, and if I list the country_code recode first then the if statement is no longer true for the other two recodes.

```
df.loc[((df['state_text'] == 'ALASKA') & (df['country_code'] != 'US')), 'flag'] = '1'
df.loc[((df['state_text'] == 'ALASKA') & (df['country_code'] != 'US')), 'state_code'] = 'AK'
df.loc[((df['state_text'] == 'ALASKA') & (df['country_code'] != 'US')), 'country_code'] = 'US
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the column names into `loc`:

```
df.loc[((df['state_text'] == 'ALASKA') & (df['country_code'] != 'US')), 
       ['flag', 'state_text', 'country_code']
      ] = ['1', 'AK', 'US']
```

Sample data:

```
  state_text country_code  flag
0     ALASKA           CA     0
1         OH           US     0
```

output after the code:

```
  state_text country_code flag
0         AK           US    1
1         OH           US    0
```

Comment: This is very clever.  The only problem is I get a KeyError for ['flag'] not in index. This field does not exist in the dataframe.  Do I need to initialize it first?  If so, how do I do that?  Interesting I don't get this error when I run the line with flag by itself.

Comment: @SAS2PYTHON it works on my system even if `flag` is not there. You may have older version of Pandas. In which case, yes, just `df['flag'] = '0'` before that line.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.